# Quale preposizione usare dopo "Comunico il mio interesse"?

Tags: prepositions

La frase *sono interessato a questo lavoro* è corretta; mi suona corretta anche *sono interessato a **fare** questo lavoro*.

Ma quale tra le seguenti lo è?

1. *Comunico il mio interesse in questo lavoro*
2. *Comunico il mio interesse per questo lavoro*
3. *Comunico il mio interesse a questo lavoro*
4. *Comunico il mio interesse verso questo lavoro*

Personalmente trovo la 3 strana e penso sia sbagliata; mi viene spontaneo utilizzare invece la 1.

O forse un'altra forma sarebbe preferibile?

Forse, al fine di trovare una risposta esatta, se esiste, gioverebbe associare un complemento a ciascuna delle varianti?

(Questa frase trova posto in una lettera di candidatura per un posto di lavoro.)

Comment: @FedericoPoloni, pensi che adesso va meglio?

Comment: Personalmente l'uso di “in” mi suona un po' inglese (“he developed an interest in art”) e opterei per “per”.

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis Sicuramente, secondo me! Sia chiaro, la domanda andava benissimo anche prima, era solo un commento così al volo. :)

Comment: @DaG: Sul GDLI ([[1](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI08/00000238.jpg)] e [[2](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI08/00000239.jpg)]) ho trovato "avere o prendere interesse in una faccenda, in un contratto, in un bene" e "avere interesse in qualche cosa o con qualcosa", ma credo che il significato sia diverso e non so se si tratti di espressioni arcaiche. Si trova anche "avere interesse di fare qualcosa".

Comment: E, cercando "interesse in questo campo" su [Google Libri](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22interesse+in+questo+campo%22&client=firefox-b-m&sxsrf=ALeKk03FnjorunRMUJlnRiVRl7_gWF6nNQ:1585906216489&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiH9biF-cvoAhUx0uAKHbdaCycQ_AUICygG), se ne trovano parecchie occorrenze.

Comment: @Charo: Per quanto riguarda il GDLI, hai ragione, ma hai visto che quegli usi hanno significati specifici diversi da “essere interessati a”? Per esempio “avere interesse in una faccenda” si riferisce per esempio al fatto di essere socio di un'impresa.

Comment: Sì, @DaG: ho detto prima che mi sembrava che il significato fosse diverso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anche a me come a Dag suona leggermente meglio la 2 (*per*) personalmente. Il [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/interesse) nei suoi esempi usa sia *a* che *per*. Sembra che usi di preferenza la preposizione *a* quando si parla di cose e *per* quando si parla di persone, ma l'esempio della seconda riga non segue questa regola (grazie @Benedetta per la segnalazione!).

> prendere i. alla lettura, allo studio, al gioco;
>
> non mostra interesse per nessuna cosa;
>
> avere, mostrare i. per qualcuno; cominciò a prendere i. per quella ragazza;
>
> è un egoista che non ha interesse per nessuno

Comment: Però, nella seconda riga della citazione si usa “per”…

Comment: Uh, hai ragione, mi era proprio sfuggito. Ho editato.

Answer (score 0):

Direi che sono tutte accettabili, però io avverto sfumature sottili nell'uso delle diverse preposizioni, probabilmente richiamate da frasi frequenti, magari usate in ambiti diversi:

1. Comunico il mio interesse in questo lavoro
   (la preposizione *in* suggerisce un coinvolgimento, in certo modo materiale, magari già in essere, come nella frase "ho interessi in quel campo").
2. Comunico il mio interesse per questo lavoro
3. Comunico il mio interesse a questo lavoro
   (queste due mi sembrano corrette e neutre, ma la prima per me suona meglio, la preposizione "a" suonerebbe meglio se seguita da un verbo all'infinito).
4. Comunico il mio interesse verso questo lavoro
   (questa mi pare più distaccata, distante).

Come sempre, e probabilmente ancor più in una lettera di candidatura per un posto di lavoro, le sfumature possono diventare importanti. Una sfumatura può comunicare fantasia, formalità, entusiasmo, sempre che non faccia pensare a scarsa conoscenza della lingua o a un suo uso troppo burocratico; e poi molto dipende dal carattere del lettore. Credo che la frase numero 2 sia la più equilibrata.